# How to compile exisiting RPGLE program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I need to make a change to an existing and working RPGLE program.  When I do a straight compile (option 14 from PDM), the error I get is "DFTACTGRP(*NO) must be specified for a prototype that does not have the EXTPGM keyword."

I change DFTACTGRP to *NO and recompile to get "Errors were found during the binding step. See the job log for more information."  Which shows "Cause . . . . . :   No definition was found for reference
  GU_getTranslatedText in *MODULE object OR404XX in library QTEMP. The 
  definition either does not exist or is not of the same data or procedure
  type as the reference.  "

In the compile I see:

```
+D GU_getTranslatedText...                              
+D                 pr           198a   extproc('GU_-    
+D                                     getTranslatedText')   
+D                                     varying               
+D  inText                      198a   value varying   



C                   eval      XNAM =                                      
C                                GU_getTranslatedText('MONTHLY')
```

There are about 30 or so of these errors on the calls.  I made no to the existing program other than copy the source to a test library and try to compile it.

I tried contacting the original person that wrote it and the only helpful information I received was "No binding directory needed"...which I was not specifying anyway.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how I can compile it?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the moduie names/library you get when issuing `DSPPGM PGM(YOURPGM) DETAIL(*MODULE)` and `DSPPGM PGM(YOURPGM) DETAIL(*SRVPGM)` ?

Comment: Creation  Optimization  Debug  
Opt  Module      Library     Attribute   Date         Level      Data   
     OR404XX      QTEMP       RPGLE       10/15/15  *NONE         *YES

Comment: Service                                                             
Opt  Program     Library     Activation  Signature                       
     IPGENUTIL   *LIBL       *IMMED      00000000000000000000000000000000
     IPMCUTIL    *LIBL       *IMMED      A62F7C3390DC833298D73DB996EFE431
     QRNXIE      QSYS        *IMMED      D8D9D5E7C9C540404040404040404040
     QRNXIO      QSYS        *IMMED      D8D9D5E7C9D640404040404040404040
     QRNXUTIL    QSYS        *IMMED      D8D9D5E7E4E3C9D34040404040404040
     QLEAWI      QSYS        *IMMED      44F70FABA08585397BDF0CF195F82EC1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a DSPPGM to see what ACTGRP is being used then add the following control (H) spec

```
  ctl-opt dftactgrp(*NO) actgrp('xxxx');
```

or if you're stuck with fixed form...

```
h dftactgrp(*no) actgrp('xxxx')
```

where 'XXXX' is the activation group found using DSPPGM.

You might look to see if there's an existing binding directory with the reference service programs `WRKOBJ OBJ(*LIBL/*ALL) OBJTYPE(*BNDDIR)`.  You can specify binding directories to be used by using the `bnddir('xxxxx')` clause on the control spec.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will solve the problem. Compile as module then execute

```
UPDPGM PGM(YOURPGM) MODULE(YOURMODULE)
```

Comment: But it's not a module..this is the existing object....OR404      *PGM      PRODLIB   RPGLE

Comment: @geojf3 Yes but ILE *PGM are composed of *MODULE, please try compile with 15 then UPDATE...

Comment: Maybe the compiler doesn't find IPGENUTI and IPMCUTIL *SRVPGM, is there a BNDDIR keyword in your source (or /copy /include) ?

Comment: No H spec or bnddir keyword i nsource.  There are many /copy statements and one of the does bring in the code for the utilities.

Comment: I created the module and it successfully compiled.  When I did the update module I got an error "Module storage model cannot be changed. "

Comment: @geojf3 So go back to `DSPPGM PGM(YOURPGM) DETAIL(*MODULE)` then display details for  OR404XX and find on second page `Storage model` copy the value and compile your module again with STGMDL(the value), then update

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the problem here is that the compiler cannot find the function GU_getTranslatedText
This function can be located either in some service program or the program that you are trying to compile, initially consists of several modules and this function is located in another module.